# Dynamically reference name manager names in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have survey data and I want to look at respondent data by country of origin. I have 1 column of indicator variables per country and I've used Name Manager to define each country's name (e.g. China =AB1:AB100).

While I can manually look at China responses with a formula like =sumifs(A1:A100, China, 1), I want to be able to drag this formula down to fill out the following table:

China   50%

Demark  50%

Finland 59%

France  45%

Germany 48%

India   49%

Italy   45%

Is there a way to write a formula that uses the left-hand column to dynamically reference the names I've created in Name Manager? (This seems to be a step removed from INDIRECT()).

Comment: take a look at the INDIRECT function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `INDIRECT` is exactly what you want here. If your list of China, Denmark, Finland... is in B1:B7, then you can use the following:

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A100,INDIRECT(B1),1)
```

and it will compute the same as `=SUMIFS(A1:A100,China,1)` if "China" is in B1.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't quite clear. "China" is a named reference in Name Manager. I don't seem to be able to use INDIRECT() to reference a cell containing the string "China" to return the name "China" from Name Manager (returns a #REF! error). Does that help?

Comment: That's what I assumed you meant. The `INDIRECT` works for me just fine for what you are describing. Can you double check that the cell you are referencing is exactly "China" and has no extra spaces or anything and the China name has Workbook scope in the Name Manager?

Comment: Hmm. Yes on Workbook scope and name matching. Here's some additional details:
In Name Manager, "China" is defined as "=INDIRECT(A1)" where A1 has the string "Filter!A1:A100"
Since I have a number of filters I'm looking to drag down, I can achieve my goal with an INDIRECT(INDEX(MATCH())) of "China" (string, not name in Name Manager); but I'm hoping for a more readable formula